# What is the font used in the Technika logo?

Tags: font-identification

I tried to find the font via whatthefont and whatfontis tools, to no avail.
Can anyone identify this font:

[image: Technica Font]

The font is Linhof's Technika camera's logo, if that helps. Not even sure if it is a font or just a logotype.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are a few more resources you could try; it would be good if you could eliminate these first http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info. There is a good chance, however, that the logo is lettering (i.e. constructed letter by letter), not a font.

Answer (score 1):

The Logo looks like a calligraphic work and is probably not a part of any known font family. Probably, the letters were specially designed for the company.

PS Some guy used similar (but NOT exactly) font in his logo... probably you can ask him - [image]

[here](https://app.shootq.com/public/~27b627/contact)

You can use this picture to grab the whole font probably:

[image: font]

Comment: it certainly looks _engineered_ rather than "designed".

Comment: @boblet I have a doubt that design and engineering are separated %), do they?

Comment: Oh, indeed, most certainly!

Comment: Why does the logo have "GI3" in it??? :)

Comment: There are similarities but mostly they are very different than each other. Are they not?

Comment: "T" "I" "H" "E" are the same, so we have 50% match %))

Comment: some useful prototype added

Comment: What's the source for that image with the full alphabet?

Comment: Where did you get letters from that aren't in the logo text e.g. `D`, `Z`, `S` etc?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the exact font, but [Chord Black Regular](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/chord/black-regular/) is very similar except for the letter "K".

[image]

Comment: N, T, A, and E doesn't resemble much. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely the typeface for Technika was designed especially for them. [Mata Regular](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/t26/mata_regular_ot/ot_ps) is similar in spirit, if that means anything.

[image]